# Filtering a column based on another column value using DAX measure (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a slicer that filters a list based on names, the same table that the slicer references  has a column for sport, i want to filter the names in a table based on the sport that corresponds the selected name on the slicer i.e if the name chosen plays a particular sport, i want the table to show the list of all the names that play the same sport as the selected name

I tried using this measure as a filter (I'm new to power Bi in case it looks crazy) and it didn't work:
Measure =
IF(
HASONEVALUE('General info'[Name]),
MAX(
CALCULATETABLE(
FILTER('General info', 'General info'[Sport] = SELECTEDVALUE('General info'[Sport])),
ALL('General info'[Name])
)
),
BLANK()
)

Comment: So each name in the table will only ever be associated with one sport, never multiple sports?

Comment: Yes each distinct name will always  be only associated with one sport

Comment: You should format that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a separate table of names to use for the slicer, a table which is unrelated to your main table. For example, assuming you create a new table called *Names* which comprises a single column (called *Name*) of distinct names, you can then create the following **measure**:

```
=
VAR ChosenName =
    MIN ( Names[Name] )
VAR SportPlayedByChosenName =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Sport] ), 'Table'[Name] = ChosenName )
RETURN
    IF ( SUMX ( 'Table', 0 + ( 'Table'[Sport] = SportPlayedByChosenName ) ), 1, 0 )
```

You then add a slicer based on the *Names* table to the canvas, and create your chosen visual using the *Name* field from your main table, dragging the above measure into the filters pane for that visual, with the condition that it be equal to 1.